# conditional addition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
   Code      Sum      Quantity
   0         -12      0
   1          23      0
   2         -10      0
   3         -12      0
   4         100      0
   5         102      201
   6          34      0
   7         -34      0
   8         -23      0
   9         100      0
   10        100      0
   11        102      300
```

My desired dataframe would be

```
  Code      Sum      Quantity    new_sum
   0         -12      0          -12
   1          23      0           23
   2         -10      0          -10
   3         -12      0          -12
   4         100      0           0
   5         102      201         202 
   6          34      0           34
   7         -34      0          -34
   8         -23      0          -23
   9         100      0           0
   10        100      0           0
   11        102      300         302
```

Logic is

First I will check for non zero values in quantity,in above sample data we got the first non zero occurance of quantity at `index 4 which is 201` then I want to add sum column till I get positive values in row above `index 4`

I have written a code which uses if loop but,then I need to scan more than 1 million rows and it does not give me desired output.

```
for i in range(len(final_df)):
   if(final_df['Quantity'][i] != 0):
      final_df['new_sum'][i] = final_df['Sum'][i].shift(1).sum()
   else:
      final_df['new_sum'][i] = final_df['Sum'][i]
```

Comment: Can you provide a for-loop based solution which DOES give you the desired output?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Is is not giving me desired output. I do not know how to take a lag till positive values and then sum

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer after clarification...

This one will be a bit slower due to the list comprehensions and loop.

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[  0, -12,   0],
        [  1,  23,   0],
        [  2, -10,   0],
        [  3, -12,   0],
        [  4, 100,   0],
        [  5, 102, 201],
        [  6,  34,   0],
        [  7, -34,   0],
        [  8, -23,   0],
        [  9, 100,   0],
        [ 10, 100,   0],
        [ 11, 102, 300]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Code', 'Sum', 'Quantity'])

print(df)

    Code  Sum  Quantity
0      0  -12         0
1      1   23         0
2      2  -10         0
3      3  -12         0
4      4  100         0
5      5  102       201
6      6   34         0
7      7  -34         0
8      8  -23         0
9      9  100         0
10    10  100         0
11    11  102       300
```

Code:

```
# copy columns from input dataframe and invert
df1 = df[['Sum', 'Quantity']][::-1].copy()

# make an array to hold result column values
new_sum_array = np.zeros(len(df1)).astype(int)
df_sum = df1.Sum.values

# locate the indices of the pos values in "Quantity".
# these will be used for segmenting the "Sum" column values
posQ = (np.where(df1.Quantity > 0)[0])

# # don't want zero or last index value in posQ for splitting
if posQ[0] == 0:
    posQ = posQ[1:]
if posQ[-1] == len(df)-1:
    posQ = posQ[:-1]

# se (start-end)
# add first and last index to be used for indexing segments of df_sum
se = posQ.copy()
se = np.insert(se, 0, 0)
se = np.append(se, len(df))

starts = se[:-1]
ends = se[1:]

# keep only positive values from the df_sum array.
# this is used with numpy argmin to find first non-positive number
# within segments
only_pos = np.add(np.zeros(len(df)), np.where(df_sum > 0, df_sum, 0))

# split the only_positive array at Quantity locations
segs = np.array(np.split(only_pos, posQ))

# find the indices of the neg numbers within each segment
tgts = [np.argmin(x) for x in segs]

# use the indices to slice each segment and put the result into
# the result array
i = 0
for seg in segs:
    idx = np.arange(starts[i], ends[i])
    np.put(new_sum_array, idx[tgts[i]:], df_sum[idx][tgts[i]:])
    i += 1

# to add a lookback limit for adding consecutive positive df_sums,
# assign an integer value to max_lookback in next line.
# use "None" to ignore any limit
max_lookback = None
if max_lookback is not None:
    tgts = np.clip(tgts, 0, max_lookback)

# add up the values of the positive numbers in the sliced
# df_sum segments
sums = [np.sum(x[:l]) for x, l in zip(segs, tgts)]

# put those totals into the result array at positive "Quality" locations
np.put(new_sum_array, starts, sums)

# add the results to the df as "New Sum"
df1['New Sum'] = new_sum_array

# flip the dataframe back upright
df1 = df1[::-1]
# insert calculated column into original dataframe
df['new sum'] = df1['New Sum']
```

Result:

```
print(df)

    Code  Sum  Quantity  New Sum
0      0  -12         0      -12
1      1   23         0       23
2      2  -10         0      -10
3      3  -12         0      -12
4      4  100         0        0
5      5  102       201      202
6      6   34         0       34
7      7  -34         0      -34
8      8  -23         0      -23
9      9  100         0        0
10    10  100         0        0
11    11  102       300      302
```

Comment: Thank you so much. saved my day.

Comment: Is it fast on your million rows?

Comment: Yes its solving my purpose.

Comment: Just once concern,somewhere I am getting values more than the sum.

Comment: Are you trimming the values anywhere?

Comment: No trimming per se.  Is there anything unusual in your data when you are getting unexpected results?  Are there sections in Sum where positive numbers are mixed with neg values between positive Quantity locations?  I may not have fully understood all of your parameters.  If there are other qualifiers, I will modify the code.

Comment: Ohhh ya. There are other positive nos in between. how do we ignore that? I just need to do max 4 lag addition not all.

Comment: If you could post an example of a section of data related to the bad outcome, that would be helpful.

Comment: Once we found quantity which is not zero. I want to do addition of last 5 positive nos `if all are positive`

Comment: Addition should be only consecutive positive nos,once we get negative no we should stop the addition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180575/discussion-between-b2002-and-neil).

Comment: I am still getting other positive values added in the final sum. Final results will be stored in `df or df1`?

Comment: updated so that results are added to original dataframe df

Answer (score 0):

You can group the dataframe by cummulative sum of quantity in reverse order calculate all positive and sum and assign back to column

```
df['New sum'] = df[df.Sum.lt(0)]['Sum']
a = df.groupby([df.Quantity.ne(0)[::-1].cumsum()])['Sum'].apply(lambda x:x[x.ge(0)].sum())[::-1]
df['New sum'] = pd.Series(a.values,index=df[df.Quantity.ne(0)].index)
```

Out:

```
    Code    Sum Quantity    New sum
0   0   -12 0   NaN
1   1   -23 0   NaN
2   2   -12 0   NaN
3   3   100 0   NaN
4   4   102 201 202.0
5   5   -34 0   NaN
6   6   -23 0   NaN
7   7   100 0   NaN
8   8   100 0   NaN
9   9   102 300 302.0
```